# Using VBA to manipulate IE with submitting form (trouble with textarea field)

Tags: html, excel, forms, vba, internet-explorer

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have a question about using VBA to manipulate IE.

The code is about inserting data in a form of a website. Everything worked out well so far, except for the following "textarea" field:

```
<textarea cols="1" rows="1" id="id_content" name="name_content" class="htmleditor">Content of the textarea is displayed here</textarea>
```

Apart from the actual field (which is from the type textarea as mentioned above) there are also a couple more elements from type button which are included in the htmleditor.

What I want to do precisely is to change the text in the text field. So instead of "Content of the textarea is displayed here" I want to be able to write something different. If possible also change the format as well, e.g. some parts bold etc. And afterwards submit the form.

The code I use so far:

```
Dim IEApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set IEApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim htmlDocument As htmlDocument
Dim objNotes As Object
Dim strNotes As String

With IEApp
    IEApp.Visible = True
    IEApp.Navigate "..."
    Do: Loop Until IEApp.Busy = False
    Do: Loop Until IEApp.document.ReadyState = "complete"
End With

Set objNotes = IEApp.document.getElementsByName("name_content")(0)

MsgBox objNotes.innerText ' 1)
MsgBox objNotes.innerHTML ' 2)
MsgBox objNotes.outerHTML ' 3)
MsgBox objNotes.Value ' 4)

objNotes.Value = "Hello World" 'Here I want to change the text in the textfield

MsgBox objNotes.innerText ' 5)
MsgBox objNotes.innerHTML ' 6)
MsgBox objNotes.outerHTML ' 7)
MsgBox objNotes.Value ' 8)

IEApp.document.forms(0).submit
```

The MsgBox commands give the following

```
1) <p>Content of the textarea is displayed here</p>
2) &lt;p&gt;Content of the textarea is displayed here&lt;/p&gt;
3) <textarea name="name_content" class="htmleditor" id="id_content" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" rows="1" cols="1">&lt;p&gt;Content of the textarea is displayed here&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
4) <p>Content of the textarea is displayed here</p>

5) <p>Hello World</p>
6) &lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;
7) <textarea name="name_content" class="htmleditor" id="id_content" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" rows="1" cols="1">&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
8) <p>Hello World</p>
```

But after successfully submitting the form the page isn't changed.

What I tried so far:

- getElementByID instead of getElementsbyName
- search for this element by going through all the elements of the site and directly referring to it
- change the values of innerText, innerHTML, outerHTML, value
- since aria-Hidden = True trying to change this via VBA but I couldn't find a proper way
- define a new textArea variable as Object / HTMLTextAreaElement / HTMLRichtextElement / HTMLInputTextElement / HTMLAreaElement and changing the value via this, but none of the data types affected it
- setting the formula as active, focusing it but not possible to use the SendKeys function to write the text this way

Any idea what else could be done?

Comment: Looking at what failed before, I think you were on the right track. Make sure you give that element focus first, then update the value property of the element. In addition, you may need to fire an OnChange event. To fire an event: IE.Document.getElementById("MyID").FireEvent ("OnChange")

Comment: Tried this before and now again but it still is neither displayed nor changed.

Comment: Can you share the website?

Comment: Sadly not, it is an internal page. Otherwise I would have mentioned it before

Comment: Keep in mind you may need to give a different element focus after firing the OnChange event, otherwise it may not fire. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp. Without access to the site, not sure how much more help I can be. I wouldn't use sendkeys though...too many nightmares, lol.

Comment: Not working either. Well it seems I don't really have a choice except for SendKeys. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

For TextArea not use byid or byname, but byTagName
I Believe you have to use function **getElementsbyTagName**