# VBA to manipulate IE: Properly using SendKeys with waiting not possible

Tags: html, excel, forms, vba, internet-explorer

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have a question about using VBA to manipulate IE.

The code is about writing text in a field of a website. The only way to write in the field seems to be via SendKeys ([everything else failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439699/using-vba-to-manipulate-ie-with-submitting-form-trouble-with-textarea-field)). The problem with this is, that I have to change the format in between (which you can see with the "Click" command to make it bold):

```
Application.SendKeys "Here is the first text", True
IEApp.document.forms(0).elements(1).Click
Application.SendKeys "Here is the second text", True
```

Sadly the code doesn't work as planned: even though I added "True" to make sure that it waits with executing the second command, it starts writing bold somewhere in the middle of the first text. Therefore I had the idea to wait using

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

but it lost focus of the application and I couldn't send the form I am filling out in the end. My next thought was to delay it by calculating something in between without using the last command:

```
c = 1000000
For i = 1 To 100
    c = c / 7
Next i
```

This resulted in a part of the first text written out, then the format changed and the next text started with interrupting the first one.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
While IEapp.Busy
doEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

after the click event

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Code-only answers are less helpful to others. Please add some explanation of what your code does, or how it solves the problem.

Comment: Sadly it loses focus as well and I can't put the focus back on it.